# Detect when iframe & elements are completely rendered, not just html is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

So i have an embedded iframe and i need to detect when the elements are completely rendered. The jquery load() and ready() events only detect when the html is loaded and fire immediately without waiting for the iframe contents to render.

i need to change the size & position of some elements via jquery, but jquery isn't accessing them.
I think the reason it can't access the elements in the iframe is because when the jquery file is ran, the elements aren't rendered yet.

Comment: Do you control the code in the iframe?

Comment: Is the iframe content from the same origin as your main page? If not, and the iframe content is actually from a different domain, then you of course have no access to it’s content _at all_ - Same Origin Policy.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onload=function(){
    var iframe=document.getElementById('iframeWrapper');
    iframe.onload=function(){
        console.log('laod the iframe')
    };
};
```